# How to convert hash table to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert hash to array by javascript function in one line

a is hash which have value are

```
Object { 10="aa", 11="bb"}
```

and i want to convert it into

```
a=[10,"aa",11,"bb"]
```

Is there any methods which can convert it into array

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var obj = { 10: "aa", 11: "bb"};
var array = [];

for( i in obj ) {
   array.push(i);
   array.push(obj[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ob={10:"aa", 11:"bb"};

a = [];
```

one line

```
for(o in ob) a.push(Number(o), ob[o]);
```

Comment: What is the reason for adding 2 spaces to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
var obj = {
    10: 'aa',
    11: 'bb'
};
```

to translate that into the *Array* you want, we can go like

```
var array = Object.keys( obj ).map(function( name ) {
    return [ +name ? +name : name, obj[ name ] ];
}).reduce(function( a, b ) {
    return a.concat(b);
});
```